# Can't read Meta-Redirect URL in a DOMDocument

Tags: php, xpath, curl, domdocument, meta-tags

I'm trying to read the meta redirect of a website.  The data is in a curl request (I've built a stub to test with).

What's not working is the "read a URL" thing - any PHP DOMDocument experts out there able to tell me why this code isn't working?  I'm trying to get the URL out of the meta refresh tag.

```
    $r['body'] = '<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Meta Refresh Example</TITLE>'.
                 '<meta http-equiv=refresh content="12; URL=meta2.htm">'.
                 '<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bwsrstyle.css" type="text/css">'.
                 '<LINK REL="SHORTCUT ICON" href="/myicon.ico">'.
                 '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=></HEAD>'.
                 '<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">foo</BODY></HTML>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($r['body']);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$meta_redirect = $xpath->query("//meta[@http-equiv='refresh']");

foreach ($meta_redirect as $node) { 
    echo         "\nNODE: {$node->getAttribute('http-equiv')} ".
                 "\nURL: {$node->getAttribute('url')}\n";   
}
```

The 'refresh' is pulling correctly but the URL is not.

Comment: See my answer for a singe, one-liner XPath-expression solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no attribute `url=`. You need to query for the `content=` attribute.

```
 print  "\nURL: {$node->getAttribute('content')}\n";
```

And you will also have to manually split this result string up. It contains the `2; url=` prefix still. This is not something the DOM functions deal with normally.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have a wellformed XML document at all, but supposing it were wellformed then

**Use**:

```
substring-after(/*/*/meta[http-equiv="refresh"]/@content, " URL=")
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work, the '-' in 'http-equiv' triggers the error: Invalid regular expression: /*/*/meta[@http-equiv="refresh"]/@content: Range out of order in character class

Comment: @Patrick, Seems like you don't have html that is a well-formed XML document.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40413746/find-redirect-meta-in-domdocument-with-domxpath