# find redirect META in DOMDocument with DOMXPath

Tags: dom, domdocument, domxpath

I have the following HTML:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://amazingjokes.com" />
    </head>
</html>
```

I want to find the META with the redirect, so I wrote the following XPath query:

```
/html/head/meta[@http-equiv="refresh"]
```

However, the '-' in 'http-equiv' is causing an error:

> Invalid regular expression: //html/head/meta[@http-equiv="refresh"]/:
>   Range out of order in character class

How can I properly rewrite the xpath query to be able to find the meta redirect?

I experimented with this, when I remove the '-' from the HTML code and the query things work as expected, but unfortunately the 'http-equiv' is a set standard, so I can not change that. This experiment showed me I am very close...

Comment: What's the PHP code that's doing this XPath query?

Comment: $dom = new DOMDocument(); $dom->loadHTML( $content );$xpath=new DOMXPath( $dom); $redir = $xpath->query( '//meta[@http-equiv="refresh"]/@content' );

Answer (score 1):

> However, the '-' in 'http-equiv' is causing an error:
>
> Invalid regular expression: //html/head/meta[@http-equiv="refresh"]/:
> Range out of order in character class

Obviously, the XPath engine you are using is buggy.

**The XPath expression used in the question is a valid XPath 1.0 expression and it selects the wanted `<meta>` element**.

Here is an XSLT - based verification:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="/html/head/meta[@http-equiv='refresh']"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When the transformation above is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://amazingjokes.com" />
    </head>
</html>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the selected in this evaluation node is output**:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://amazingjokes.com"/>
```

Comment: I'm using the XPath engine in PHP7

Comment: @Patrick, So, make the conclusion ... This so called "XPath engine" is not a compliant XPath implementation. Maybe there is another way to evaluate XPath expressions supported in PHP, which you need to use.

Comment: ok, thanks for proving that indeed. But... PHP7 is what I have to work with. Any ways around this you know?

Comment: @Patrick, Try: `/html/head/meta[@*[name()="http-equiv"]="refresh"]`. Or, maybe, your "XPath engine doesn't supports attributes ...

Comment: This gave the same problem, you did however point me to a (very ugly) workaround: /html/head/meta[@*[name()=concat("http","-equiv")]="refresh"]. Apparently PHP7's XPath engine (seems the problem is in the RegEx engine) tries to make a regex out of any character range (a-b, or a-z), in this case 'http-equiv' is implemented as 'htt, then p-e, then quiv' or something... it seems buggy. This workaround is ugly, but at least it's a way to establish my goal using PHP7. thanks for that

Comment: @Patrick, Glad I helped find the solution. Feel free to accept the answer.